# Blank PDF generate when WriteCompatiblePdf method call of ITextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf

Hi i am using below code. When i upload some of PDF's which contain some content and after uploading, their is no content on uploaded PDF. Uploaded PDf is blank. I am using below method of ItextSharp for change the version of Orginial PDF to Defined Version.

```
private int WriteCompatiblePdf(string fileName, FileUpload filePath)
        {
            string sNewPdf = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InterfaxPath"]) + fileName;
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(filePath.FileBytes);
            // we retrieve the total number of pages
            int n = reader.NumberOfPages;
            // step 1: creation of a document-object
            iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));
            // step 2: we create a writer that listens to the document
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(sNewPdf, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite));
            //write pdf that pdfsharp can understand
            writer.SetPdfVersion(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.PDF_VERSION_1_4);
            // step 3: we open the document
            document.Open();
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfImportedPage page;
            int rotation;
            int i = 0;
            while (i < n)
            {
                i++;
                document.SetPageSize(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i));
                document.NewPage();
                page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
                rotation = reader.GetPageRotation(i);                    
                cb.AddTemplate(page, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);                    
            }
            // step 5: we close the document
            document.Close();
            return n;
        }
```

Any recommendations?

Comment: Do all PDFs you upload end up without content? Or just some? Can you provide a sample that gets corrupted? That been said, please be aware that your content copying code is very lossy; you should use a `PdfReader-PdfStamper` pair instead of your `PdfReader-PdfWriter` pair.

Comment: This will happen for some pdf's. I did'nt get any error while executing this code. But for 1 or 2 pdf's i found this issue.

Comment: If your issue only occurs for some PDFs you should supply a sample PDF to illustrate. Otherwise others can only guess.

Comment: Hi mkl, please find the link of pdf. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4KYV-9yFCBSQk9IRnE5Tl8yY2s/edit?usp=sharing, as you can see if you upload this pdf, pdf goes blank.

Comment: Well, the file does not look blank but it looks like something is missing. As if there was a filled-in Form and there now only are the fill-ins. Is that your observation, too?

Comment: Hi mkl, no actually that was the actual pdf which i have to upload, but when i upload that file a blank file uploaded into server. you can check this into the following url https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4KYV-9yFCBSS3Z4Wm9ISl9iXzQ/edit ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP provided a sample "blank" file.

As it turns out, this "blank" file does contain the desired content, it merely is way off-page.

### Details

The pages of the document have this media box definition:

```
/MediaBox[0 7072 612 7864]
```

Thus, the visible area has x coordinates in 0..612 and y coordinates in 7072..7864. When adding the imported page contents, though, the OP explicitly anchors them explicitly at the coordinates 0,0:

```
cb.AddTemplate(page, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);
```

The contents of the former page, therefore, are added in the area with y coordinates 0..792. So, they are not visible.

### Resolutions

There are different ways to resolve this issue:

1. add the contents at the position with the correct coordinates, i.e. use

   cb.AddTemplate(page, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, x, y);

   where `x` and `y` are `Left` and `Bottom` of `reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1)` (a `Rectangle`); or
2. normalize the page size rectangle for the `Document` constructor to be based in 0,0; or
3. use a `PdfStamper` with the `PdfReader` instead of the `PdfWriter` and use it to select the desired version.

Answer (score 1):

it's because you're not set any text to be written in the PDF. this is a simple example how to write text

```
 string newFile = @"C:\the path\file.pdf";
 Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 42, 35);
 PdfWriter write = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(newFile,  
 FileMode.Create));    

 doc.Open(); // open the connection
 Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("text to be displayed in the first paragraph");
doc.Add(p1); // close the connection
```

this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/686994/Create-Read-Advance-PDF-Report-using-iTextSharp-in#1) will tell you the proper way to write from iTextSharp more advanced

Comment: I think, you did not see code properly. Their is already that code i.e.  iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1)); which already get the content of source pdf and then right.