# Cannot stamp certain PDFs

Tags: pdf, itext

PDF stamping works for nearly every document I have tried.  However, a client scanned some pages and his computer generated a PDF document that is resistant to stamping.  The embedded image files are in JBIG2 format, but I am not sure if that is important. I have debugged the PDF with Apache's pdfbox, and I can see the text is embedded.  It just doesn't show up.

Here is the PDF that won't stamp: http://demo.clearvillageinc.com/plans.pdf

And my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    string stamp = "<div style=\"color:#F00;\">Reviewed for Code Compliance</div>";
    string fileName = @"C:\temp\source.pdf";
    string outputFileName = @"C:\temp\source-output.pdf";

    // Open a destination stream.
    using (var destStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream()) {
        using (var sourceReader = new PdfReader(fileName)) {

            // Convert the HTML into a stamp.
            using (var stampData = FromHtml(stamp)) {
                using (var stampReader = new PdfReader(stampData)) {
                    using (var stamper = new PdfStamper(sourceReader, destStream)) {
                        stamper.Writer.CloseStream = false; 
                        // Add the stamp stream to the source document.
                        var stampPage = stamper.GetImportedPage(stampReader, 1);

                        // Process all of the pages in the source document.
                        for (int i = 1; i <= sourceReader.NumberOfPages; i++) {
                            var canvas = stamper.GetOverContent(i);
                            canvas.AddTemplate(stampPage, 0, -50);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Finished.  Save the file.    
        using (var fs = new System.IO.FileStream(outputFileName, FileMode.Create)) {
            destStream.Position = 0;
            destStream.CopyTo(fs);
        }
    }
}

public static System.IO.Stream FromHtml(string html) {
    var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

    // Convert html to pdf.
    using (var document = new iTextSharp.text.Document()) {
        var writer = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
        writer.CloseStream = false;

        document.Open();

        using (var sr = new System.IO.StringReader(html)) {
            XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, document, sr);
        }
    }

    ms.Position = 0; // Reset for reading.
    return ms;
}
```

Comment: Related to [Blank PDF generate when WriteCompatiblePdf method call of ITextSharp](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23996258/1729265). `/MediaBox[0 7072 612 7864]` seems to be in fashion nowadays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One part of a page definition is the "MediaBox" which controls the page's size. This property takes two locations that specify the coordinates of two opposite corners of a rectangle. Although not required, most PDFs specify the lower left corner first followed by the upper right corner. Also, most PDF use `0x0` for the lower left  and then whatever the page's width and height for the top corner. So an 8.5x11 inch PDF would be `0,0` and `612,792` (8.5 * 72 = 612 and 11 * 72 = 792) and this would be written as `0,0,612,792`.

Your scanned PDF, however, has for whatever reason decided to treat `0,7072` as the lower left corner and `614,7864` as the top right corner. That still gives us (almost) an 8.5x11 page size but if you try to draw something at `0,0` it will be 7,072 pixels below the actual page. You can see this in Acrobat Pro by zooming out very far (1% for me), picking Tools, Edit Object and then doing a Select All. You should see something way far down selected, too.

To get around this, you need to respect the page's boundaries.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= sourceReader.NumberOfPages; i++) {
    //Get the page to be stamped
    var pageToBeStamped = sourceReader.GetPageSize(i);

    var canvas = stamper.GetOverContent(i);

    //Offset our new page by 50 pixels off of the destination page's bottom
    canvas.AddTemplate(stampPage, pageToBeStamped.Left, pageToBeStamped.Bottom - 50);
}
```

The code above gets the rectangle for the imported page and uses bottom offset by 50 pixels (from your original code). Also, although not a problem in your case, we use the imported page's actual left edge instead of just zero.

This code can still break, however. The math in the first paragraph uses `72` which is the default for PDFs but this can be changed. Most people don't change it but most people also don't change `0,0`. Currently your `-50` assumes the `72` which gives the visual perception of moving the stamp about seven-tenths of an inch from the top edge. If you run into this scenario you'll want to look into [retrieving the user unit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14588654/231316).

Also, as I said in the first paragraph, most applications use lower left upper right but this isn't a hard rule. Someone could specify upper right and bottom left or even top left and bottom right. This is a hard one to take into account but it is something that you should at least be aware of.